# makensis gives error on unix with exact same script that works on windows

Tags: nsis

I wrote a NSIS installer script that builds fine on Windows, however I need it to build on *nix OSes too. When I run it on OS X I get the following error..

```
Usage: !define ([/date|/utcdate] symbol [value]) | (/file symbol filename) | (/math symbol val1 OP val2)
    OP=(+ - * / % & | ^)
Error in script "/Users/john/Development/java/vordio/src/main/app-resources/win-installer.nsi" on line 6 -- aborting creation process
```

This is the line of the script that is failing..

```
 !define VORDIO_ICON "${PROJECT_DIR}\src\main\app-resources\vordio_logo_64x64_win_icon.ico"
```

I can't see anything wrong with it but I tried adding /file which didn't help, nor did changing file path separators.

Anyone had this NSIS problem?

Comment: maybe use forward slashes?

Comment: Backward slashes shouldn't be a problem. Would be interesting to know the contents of the PROJECT_DIR constant. I didn't have a problem with my version of that line, compiling on OS X (MakeNSIS v12-Mar-2015.cvs)

Comment: The project dir and other constants are .. Command line defined: "PROJECT_DIR="/Users/john/Development/java/vordio""
Command line defined: "PROJECT_BUILD_DIR="/Users/john/Development/java/vordio/target""
Command line defined: "PROJECT_VERSION="4.3.3""

Comment: You should probably use different quotes inside or outside, e.g. 'PROJECT_DIR="/Users/john/Development/java/vordio"'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!define` will print that error if you are passing too many parameters. This can happen if quotes terminates the string early:

```
!define bar 'BAR" "oops'
!define foo "${bar}\baz" ; Expands to !define foo "BAR" "oops\baz"
```

I assume the problem is related to how you are using -D on the command-line to set PROJECT_DIR. You should not quote the value part (a path in your case), you should quote the entire name=value part. How you do that is controlled by the C library implementation, it is responsible for splitting the command-line into individual arguments (and possibly removing quotes). The official NSIS Windows build uses Visual C++ and it is quite forgiving and allows at least these 5 variations:

1. makensis "-Dname=value" setup.nsi
2. makensis -"Dname=value" setup.nsi
3. makensis -D"name=value" setup.nsi
4. makensis "-Dname="value"" setup.nsi
5. makensis -D"name="value"" setup.nsi

...and all of these should display

> Command line defined: "name=value"

because the Microsoft implementation has some crazy quote handling.

Add `!warning ">${PROJECT_DIR}<"` to your script and change the way you call makensis until there are no quotes between the angle brackets...

Comment: The first thing I did was take all quotes off and it worked. I realise now that the quotes are probably unecessary anyway as makensis is being called with an array by a build tool, not via the command line. I don't think spaces affect it when called that way.